# Rubiks Cube Landing on Red

Tags: probability, statistics

A Rubik’s cube in which each side is painted one of six colors (white, orange, red, blue, green and yellow).

Suppose each side of the Rubik’s cube consists of only one color, if the Rubik’s cube is tossed 6 times what is the probability that the cube will land on the red side at least 4 times?

Comment: This can be calculated by using distribution of $Binomial(\frac{1}{6})$. This is also the question related to dice rolls and whether lands a specific face of dice a certain amount of times

Comment: I was going for (C(6,4) + C(6,5) + C(6,6))/(6^6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Add up the following:**

- The probability that it lands on the red side exactly $4$ times is $\dbinom{6}{4}\cdot\dfrac{5^2}{6^6}=\dfrac{375}{46656}$
- The probability that it lands on the red side exactly $5$ times is $\dbinom{6}{5}\cdot\dfrac{5^1}{6^6}=\dfrac{30}{46656}$
- The probability that it lands on the red side exactly $6$ times is $\dbinom{6}{6}\cdot\dfrac{5^0}{6^6}=\dfrac{1}{46656}$

---

**Another way to look at it:**

- The total number of ways it can land is $6^6=46656$
- The number of ways it can land on the red side exactly $4$ times is $\dbinom{6}{4}\cdot5^2=375$
- The number of ways it can land on the red side exactly $5$ times is $\dbinom{6}{5}\cdot5^1=30$
- The number of ways it can land on the red side exactly $6$ times is $\dbinom{6}{6}\cdot5^0=1$

---

In either case, the probability of it landing on the red side at least $4$ times is $\dfrac{375+30+1}{46656}$

Comment: I didn't mean to. I'm new to this forum, and didn't know what the check mar did. I just accepted it.