# If a Rubik’s cube is tossed 6 times what is the probability that the cube will land on the red side at least 4 times?

Tags: probability

A Rubik’s cube in which each side is painted one of six colors (white, orange, red, blue, green and yellow).

Suppose each side of the Rubik’s cube consists of only one color, if the Rubik’s cube is tossed 6 times what is the probability that the cube will land on the red side at least 4 times?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level.

Comment: This question [was asked earlier today](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941783/rubiks-cube-landing-on-red)

Answer (score 0):

Probability of landing on red colour in one tossed is $ 1/6 $. So we can use binomial distribution with $ n= 6 $ and $ p= 1/6 $. Probability mass function of binomial is $ P(X=x)= {n\choose x}(1/6)^x (5/6)^{n-x} $.
So required probability is $ P(X\geq 4)= P(X=4)+ P(X=5)+ P(X=6) $